# Redirecting Google search to HTTPS with Privoxy 

Tags: linux, privoxy

I tried this in the `user.action` file:

```
{ +redirect{s@http://www.google.*/search@https://encrypted.google.com/search@} }
.google.
```

But it doesn't work. My goal is to redirect from this:

```
http://www.google.*/searchBLA-BLA
```

to this:

```
https://encrypted.google.com/searchBLA-BLA
```

It could be `de`, `pl`, etc.; that's why I need the `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule works for me with TLD's .de, .pl:

```
{+redirect{s@^http://[^/]*/search\?q=([^&]*).*@https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=$1@}}
.google.*/search
```

You will find great examples how to use `redirect` in the Privoxy [Action Files: redirect section](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#REDIRECT) documentation.

If you want to debug your rules enable `debug 128` in the main configuration file.